# d3.js mouse over show details about node by using two different json file

Tags: javascript, d3.js

in my case, I would like to build a mouse event in d3.js to implement each node's details. But I have to use different two json file to achieve this.

Based on the example of [Simple d3.js tooltip](http://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/a22c42db65eb00d4e369). I did my own code in following part:

```
d3.json("https://quarkbackend.com/getfile/otto-gao24/places-json", function(error,cities) {

var lineFunction = d3.svg.line()
    .x(function(d) {return d[0];})
    .y(function(d) {return d[1];})
    .interpolate("linear");
    // append some cities:
    g2.selectAll(".cities")
      .data(d3.entries(cities))
      .enter()
      .append("circle")
      .attr("transform",function(d) { return "translate("+ projection(d.value) + ')'; })
      .attr("r",1.5)
      .attr("fill","white")
      .attr("stroke","steelblue")
```

This part shows the place nodes in the map, and I imported the first json file to build the nodes. But from now there is not detail information in it. Then I have to add a mouse over event in each node. Such as

```
.attr("fill","white")
.attr("stroke","steelblue")
.on("mouseover", function(d) {
    div.transition()
        .duration(200)
        .style("opacity", .9);
    div .html(function (d){
      d3.json("{% url 'places_information:json' %}", function(data) {
        return data.networks.name;
      });
    })
        .style("left", (d3.event.pageX) + "px")
        .style("top", (d3.event.pageY - 28) + "px");
  })
.on("mouseout", function(d) {
    div.transition()
         .duration(500)
         .style("opacity", 0);
  });
```

The second part shows I imported the next json file to show the details about the nodes. But in my result, there shows [nothing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uwxel.png). I think the problem is in the imported file.

The first json file is for placing my cities in map, as shown:

```
{
"TYO": [139.76, 35.68],
"BKK": [100.48, 13.75],
"BER": [13.40, 52.52],
"NYC": [-74.00, 40.71],
"SIN": [103.75, 1.36],
"BSB": [-47.43, -15.67]
}
```

And the second json file is shown my cities' ids, names and other properties. As the following:

```
id: "dfc69b95-915f-475c-8800-db6c4e15c290"
name: "TYO"
original_status: "ACTIVE"
....
```

I mean that the second json-file's information will show when I mouse over the city node.

Could you please tell me how to import the other json file in one existed json file, and how can I show the details by using mouse event?

Thanks in heart.

Comment: There are two types of JavaScript programmers: ... and those who don't. Those who understand asynchronous code...

Comment: Joking aside, you have to **nest** the two `d3.json` functions.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado Thanks for your reply, I have thought about nesting. But I only know that nesting could come from one data, in my case, I should import two data(json-file), I am not aware how to nest them. Could you please tell me more specifically? Or you might give me some example. Thanks.

Comment: I meant *nesting the d3.json functions*. I can show you how to do it, but preferably knowing your data arrays. What is that `"{% url 'places_information:json' %}"`? The best idea is creating a working plunker or blockbuilder.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado You can see my updated question, I add some json information in it. May help you understand my thought. Thanks in heart.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`d3.json` is **asynchronous**. This means that you cannot put it inside a `mouseover` event.

Instead of that, load all the files (2, 3 or more, doesn't matter) with data *before* painting the dataviz. You can use `d3.queue` or, in a simpler approach, nest the `d3.json` functions:

```
d3.json("data1.json", function(data1) {
    d3.json("data2.json", function(data2) {

        //code using both data files here

    })
})
```

Here is a plunker showing it. Have a look at the data files. In the plunker, hover over the circles and look at your console: https://plnkr.co/edit/MvIqHtCBSjI1574XyV9V?p=preview

Basically, inside the `mouseover` function, the information in the `data2.json` file is retrieved based on the information in the `data1.json` file, used to create the circles.

Follow the same approach, changing your code accordingly.

Comment: yes, you are absolutely correct. I have misunderstood before, now I GOT it and it works. You are my lifesaver, thanks:>)